# how to set a timeout for a random generated number

Tags: python

I want to generate a random number which will expire after 10 mins how can I do that.
For generating the random number I have used the uuid4 module I can generate a random number like this.

```
 import uuid
 random_num = uuid.uuid4().hex.upper()[0:10]
```

when I print random_num my initial output will be

```
  QAZ1234I87
```

but after 10 minutes if I print the random_num I want like this.

```
  None
```

but I don't no how to set time out.

Comment: You can use `import time` and `time.sleep(10*60)` to sleep for 10 mins and reset the variable to `None` then. Please give us more details about what excactly you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

- if you just want to remove the item from your data after some time, you can just... do that? Set a timer (create a thread and make it [sleep](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html?highlight=sleep#time.sleep) or use [signal.alarm](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#signal.alarm)) and once the timer is hit, replace, reset or unset the value
- if you want something like a *code* which is only valid for some time, then you want either some sort of *signed token* (the token carries all the information *including its timeout* and has a signature you can verify for tampering) or store the data (e.g. in your database have a table which associates tokens with timeouts, tokens are only "valid" if they're in the table and not timed-out yet, you may or may not want to remove the timed out tokens once in a while depending on your specific needs)

Incidentally going through UUID just to get 5 random bytes seems like a bit of a waste, you can just use `os.urandom(5).hex()`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `threading.Thread`:

```
import random
from threading import Thread
import time

my_random_var = [random.randint(0, 1000)] # replace with [uuid.uuid4().hex.upper()[0:10]] if you want to use your code

print(my_random_var[0])
def expire(duration=1):
    time.sleep(duration)
    my_random_var[0] = None 

duration = 1 # in seconds
t = Thread(target=expire, args=(duration,))
t.start()

# you add your other code
time.sleep(2)  
print(my_random_var[0])
```

output:

```
299
None
```

you can use a list to store your random number and a thread to update your list after your wanted amount of time